Write IOS application accepting "open with" input documents
I am trying to write an IOS application which accepts PDF documents from other applications. I succeeded in writing an app which works on Xcode iPhone emulator. However, when I push my application to a real iPhone device, the iPhone proposes me my application in the list of applications where I can send the PDF, but when selecting it, the application opens, but does not process the document.
To achieve this, I declare my App with a DocumentGroup:
@main
struct ScannerImporterApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: ScannerImporterDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(doc_name: file.document.title, doc_content: file.document.text)
        }

        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(doc_name: "", doc_content: "")
         }
    }
}

Then, I declare my class which manages the document as is :
extension UTType {
    static var exampleText: UTType {
        UTType(importedAs: "com.adobe.pdf")
    }
}

struct ScannerImporterDocument: FileDocument 
{
    var text: String
    var title: String
    
    init(title: String = "My title", text: String = "Hello, world!") 
    {
        print("TestDocument : init")
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
    }
    
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.exampleText] }
    
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        
        print("TestDocument : init 2")
        let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents
        
        title = configuration.file.filename!
        text = (data?.base64EncodedString())!
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        print("TestDocument : init 3")
        let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
        return .init(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}

With this code, when executed in iPhone emulator, the application is showing a file selector view when it is opened. And if the user sends a PDF to this app from another app, this PDF is managed by the app by creating a new ScannerImporterDocument, and providing its content in "configuration" variable.
When executed on a real iPhone, it shows a file selector view when open, but it does not react to other apps sending a PDF to it (when such action is done, the only result is that the application is shown in foreground, but still with file selector).
Any idea how I can solve this issue?
Note that I do not need to display the file selector view when opening the app. So, if there is another solution without using the DocumentGroup, it can be OK for me too.
